# lazylist adapter issue while scrolling

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, listadapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {         
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    View vi= convertView;

    if(convertView==null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        viewHolder.content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.f_content);
        viewHolder.cat_id  = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.c_id);
        viewHolder.fact_id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.f_id);
        vi.setTag(viewHolder); 
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }   

    HashMap<String, String> fact = new HashMap<String, String>();
    fact = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    viewHolder.fact_id.setText(fact.get("_id"));
    viewHolder.cat_id.setText(fact.get("cat_id"));
    viewHolder.content.setText(fact.get("fact_content"));

    return vi;
}
```

I have created a `LazyAdapter` that extends a `BaseAdaper` to use with `ListView`.

The this adapter populates data in ListView. When I click on first 4 visible list items it prints the value of that item.
Problem is when I scroll down the list view and click on item 5. The app crashes saying null pointer exception. Log trace is here for reference.

> 05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at com.example.facts.MainActivity$3.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:100)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3569)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1831)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4389)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
>   05-13 23:10:43.943: E/AndroidRuntime(3360):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

The Onclick Methods is like this:

```
// Click event for single list row
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

    RelativeLayout node = (RelativeLayout)parent.getChildAt(position);
    TextView fact = (TextView) node.findViewById(R.id.c_id);
    Log.d("ListItem Clicked", "id: " + id + " position: "
        + position + " artist " + fact.getText());
}
});
```

Comment: You need to show us the `onItemClick` method, that's where the error is.

Comment: @ashishduh i have edit the question. included the onclick method on list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to revisit your `onItemClickListener` implementation.

You should not need to access parent at all for what you are trying to do. Try this.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {

        TextView fact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.c_id);
        Log.d("ListItem Clicked", "id: " + id + " position: "
        + position + " artist " + fact.getText());
    }
});
```

The view argument supplied in the method is actually the view being click on.

> view; The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)

Please refer to [AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for more details.

The parent is there to help you identified which `AdapterView` that is being acted on. For example, say if you have two `ListAdapter` but only want to use one listener then it going to help you specify which is the one.

Comment: In that case, @ZeeshanAli please accept my answer. Accepting answer will letting people knows that the issue is resolved. If someone stumble upon the same issue, they may find this question here. Then they know what to do next.

Comment: i wish i could. i dont have much reputation yet to accept answers

Comment: I see, no problem then. Don't forget to come back when you can then. :)